# In browser's default HTML5 video player, how to detect when user enables/disables subtitles via CC button?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, subtitle

I want to allow the user to enable subtitles using the browser's default video player, but I'm trying to skirt around the subtitle styling inconsistency between browsers (especially the limitations in IE/Edge). I plan on using my own styled div overlayed on top of the video, and I need to be able to show and hide it according to whether the video's TextTrack object has it's mode property set to "disabled", "hidden", or "showing". This mode is controlled by the user through the video player's built-in CC button, and I need to be able to detect when a change is triggered. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to loop through all of the text tracks and see if any are "showing". I'm sure you've already seen this but if not its worth a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/Adding_captions_and_subtitles_to_HTML5_video and here are more details on the textTrack.Mode property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextTrack/mode

Comment: I've been able to successfully check and/or change the TextTrack mode, but I haven't been able to figure out an elegant method for detecting when the user changes that mode via the player's built-in CC button. When they choose to disable the subtitles via that button, it changes the track's mode to "disabled". When they enable the subtitles via that button, the track's mode changes to "showing", but I haven't been able to find out if that action fires off an event that I can use. I know I could set an interval and continuously check the track's mode but I was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: @Will just poll it, simplest solution.